# Return single item from $element with simple-html-dom-parser

Tags: php, arrays, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

New to the simple-html-dom-parser and have a question.

Assuming `$element` is an array, how can I return a specific item (an image in this case) from the array. I have tried `$element[1]` and `$element->childNodes ([1])` to no avail.

```
$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
    {
    echo $element;
    }
```

[Simple-html-dom-parser api](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm)

Comment: arrays are zero based. please refer to http://php.net/array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation you posted](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm), find takes a second optional argument which is the index of the element you're looking for. So, for example, you could do `$html->find('img', 1)` and it would return the first img element it could find.

Hope this helps.

Comment: $img1 = $html->find('img', 1);